# How to inject the bean id with Spring EL?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-el

I want to pass the `id` from the XML config to the constructor of the bean. I don't want to implement [BeanNameAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) to do this. My preferred way to do so would be a Spring EL expression like this:

```
<bean id="ws1" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="#{#this.id}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```

However, `#this` refers to `BeanExpressionContext` in this case, what doesen't contain the `id`.

Is there a way to access the `id` (`ws1` in my example) with a Spring EL expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know the bean id in the target `MyClass` instance, you should consider to implement `BeanNameAware`:

```
 * Interface to be implemented by beans that want to be aware of their
 * bean name in a bean factory. Note that it is not usually recommended
 * that an object depends on its bean name, as this represents a potentially
 * brittle dependence on external configuration, as well as a possibly
 * unnecessary dependence on a Spring API.
```

But right, you can't get access to it from SpEL. OTOH I don't see big problem in your sample to copy/paste `ws1` to that `id` constructor arg value.

Comment: Since I don't want to implement `BeanNameAware` I will copy the name. It's not a big deal, but I looked for a more elegant solution.

Comment: The `id` is so specific attribute that you can't do anything with that, even use Properties Placeholder. Now consider you move to Java config...